# Reading a text file with SSIS with CRLF or LF

Tags: sql, ssis

Running into an issue where I receive a text file that has LF's as the EOL.  Sometimes they send the file with CRLF's as the EOL.  Does anyone have any good ideas on how I can make SSIS use either one as the EOL?

It's a very easy convert operation with notepad++ to change it to what ever I need, however, it's manual and I want it to be automatic.

Thanks,

EDIT.  I fixed it (but not perfect) by using [Swiss File Knife](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/) before the dataflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the OP's vote for Swiss File Knife.

To integrate that, I had to add an Execute Process Task:
[image: exeproc]

However, I have a bunch of packages that run For-Each-File loops, so I needed some BIML - maybe this'll help the next soul.

```
<ExecuteProcess Name="(EXE) Convert crlf for <#= tableName #>"
              Executable="<#= myExeFolder #>sfk.exe">
  <Expressions>
    <Expression PropertyName="Arguments">
      "crlf-to-lf " +  @[User::sFullFilePath]
    </Expression>
  </Expressions>
</ExecuteProcess>
```

Answer (score 7):

If the line terminators are always one or the other, I'd suggest setting up 2 File Connection Managers, one with the "CRLF" row delimiter, and the other with the "LF" row delimiter.

Then, create a boolean package variable (something like @IsCrLf) and scope this to your package.  Make the first step in your SSIS package a [Script Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141752.aspx), in which you read in a file stream, and attempt to discover what the line terminator is (based on what you find in the stream).  Set the value of your variable accordingly.

Then, after the Script Task in your Control Flow, create 2 separate Data Flows (one for each File Connection Manager) and use a [Precedence Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141261.aspx) set to "Expression and Constraint" on the connectors to specify which Data Flow to use, depending on the value of the @IsCrLf variable.

Example of the suggested Control Flow below.

[image: Example SSIS Control Flow]

Comment: Nicely done.  I think for simplicity sake though I'm going to stick with SwissFileKnife.  The data flow steps after the flat file are pretty long and complicated and I'd rather not duplicate the logic.

Comment: If they're not large files then you could in your Script Task, load the entire file into an object variable held in memory and pass that to a single Data Flow using a Script Source.  Probably no advantage to this over SwissFileKnife though. That's a nice utility, definitely checking it out!

Comment: While this is a valid solution, is it just me or is this another reason to hate SSIS?

Comment: There are certainly plenty of other workarounds (Script Task as a source?) but yeah, there's definitely a window there to make some sort of advanced/dynamic configuration for Flat File connection managers, maybe introduce a more intelligent behaviour based on certain file properties (name etc).  Maybe a window to develop your own custom component? :-p

Answer (score 1):

how about a derived column with the REPLACE operation after your file source to change the CRLFs to LFs?

Comment: Only issue with that is, you'd need to load the file using a File Connection Manager BEFORE you can use a Derived Column Transformation in the Data Flow.