# SSIS Text Qualifier not working on last column

Tags: csv, ssis, flat-file

My flat files fields are tab delimited (\t) with a quotation mark (") text qualifier, and each row is linefeed (LF) separated.

My SSIS package works great when

- no fields are text qualified
- any field EXCEPT the last column is text qualified

When the last column is text qualified my package errors out saying it couldn't find the delimiter for my last column ... any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some more information to help?  Open the Connection Manager for your Flatfile.  Click on Advanced.  For your last column, what is the value for ColumnDelimiter and TextQualified?  Post a pic?

Answer (score 0):

In a programmer's life, 3 problems (that often take hours to track down) are certain: permissions, case sensitivity, and line endings.

In my case, it is line endings.  When a CRLF is pressed against the text qualifier ("), SSIS apparently doesn't interpret the text qualifier correctly, but does see the line break.

Here's what my setup looked like when I was having issues:
[image: columninfo_a]
[image: preview_a]

Here's what my setup looked like after changing the column delimiter:
[image: columninfo_b]
[image: preview_b]

The official answer here then is to change the line endings.  The unfortunate side effect of that is to change a package that works on all the other files - leading to a need to convert files with CRLF to LF before hitting this package, or ending up with unsightly workarounds as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740572/reading-a-text-file-with-ssis-with-crlf-or-lf).

Answer (score 0):

use this application on your SSIS Execute task
http://www.softsea.com/review/U2WIN.html

and put in flat file folder

Answer (score 0):

I tried set TextQualified = 'False' on your last column to see if it helps